# Regex get all content between third (:) and characters

Tags: javascript

I have this expression that has a static text that doesn't change `.zzz` .

> aaa:aaa:aaa:a1b1c1d1.zzz&bbbb&bbbbbb&bbbbbb

how can i get `a1b1c1d1.zzz` from it using Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using regex (not egex):

```js
var string = "aaa:aaa:aaa:3efb72affd217a759b5f1765&dn=5.zzz&bbbb&bbbbbb&bbbbbb";
string = string.replace(/^(?:[^:]+:){3}(.*?zzz).*/, "$1");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: i edited my question, in my expression everything is changing except `.zzz`

Comment: @ler My answer (and also the one given by GetOffMyLawn) do not depend on the content of what you are trying to match, but rather the position in which it sits inside your input string.  So, "changing" doesn't change my answer.

Comment: but it doesn't work for example in this situation `aaa:aaa:aaa:3efb72affd217a759b5f1765&dn=5.zzz&bbbb&bbbbbb&bbbbbb`

Comment: that's why i mentioned static `.zzz`, so it will start from the third `:` until `.zzz` no mater how many chars are in between or if they are special character there

Comment: @ler I have updated my answer per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this without regex (mostly):

```js
let str = 'aaa:aaa:aaa:a1b1c1d1.zzz&bbbb&bbbbbb&bbbbbb'

let result = str.split(':', 4).pop().split(/(\.zzz)/, 2).join('')

console.log(result)
```